# Playing video stored on cloud platform in HTML5

Tags: video-streaming, google-cloud-storage

I have a video stored on Google cloud storage, for which I made the bucket public by adding permission to "allUsers" with a role of "Storage Object Viewer".

I am using the item's URL as source for my HTML5 video tag. Video plays fine if Im logged in to Chrome (which makes sense), but doesn't on other users devices. 
Simply redirecting users to the files URL **does** allow everyone to play the video. The problem is that page is not part of my app, and as a result I can't style it as I  want.

What steps am I missing in making my video publically accessible through an HTML5 video tag?

```
/*JS/REACT*/
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source
        src="bucket_url" 
        type="video"
    />
</video>
```

Comment: When the video doesn't play, what errors or messages are reported?  Maybe open up chrome and open the developer tools to look at logs.

Comment: No errors in devtools:(

Comment: What's the pattern of your `bucket_url` variable?

Comment: Could you please specify where it is not working? if it is web or mobile, and for which specific browsers? I tested a similar setup and, for me, it worked both on an Android device and on an iPhone. As @guillaumeblaquiere said, knowing the url pattern would also help us identify any issues with that.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere @pessolato, I tested it on Android, IOS and PC, always in google Chrome. My file's URL  is as follow: `https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucket-name/file-name.mp4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that you use is for accessing to the object through the google cloud console. It's not your aim.

You have to use the public link of the file, with this file pattern:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>/path/to/file
```

For finding this link on the console, click on the link icon close to `public` label.
[image]

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was under the impression I was supposed to use the link from the object details page. Thanks a lot Guillaume:)

Comment: @SteveA when i copy my url and paste in to the browser then video not play.